# How can I leave columns untouched with aggregate in R

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

I have a large dataframe with experiments with different parameters. Each combination of parameters have several executions:

```
PROFILE TIME   NTHREADS PARAM1 PARAM2 PARAM3
prof1   3.01   1        4      10     1
prof1   2.90   1        4      10     1
prof1   3.02   1        4      10     1
prof1   1.52   1        4      10     2
prof1   1.60   1        4      10     2
...
```

I am using aggregate to obtain the best time for each combination of profile & nthreads:

```
data_aggregated <- aggregate(data$TIME, 
                             by = list(PROFILE = data$PROFILE, 
                                       NTHREADS = data$NTHREADS), 
                             FUN = min)
```

That return a new dataframe like this:

```
PROFILE NTHREADS TIME
prof1   1        1.52
prof1   2        0.9
prof2   1        1.41
prof2   2        0.88
...
```

What I want is to obtain the values of PARAM1, PARAM2, PARAM3 **for the aggregated row in each case (the one with minimum time)**. For now, I look in first dataframe the row where PROFILE, TIME and NTHREADS are equal to the ones in the second dataframe, but maybe there is an easier way?

Comment: `which.min(TIME)` should also work for you

Comment: Maybe you have to add a step further to merge the two dataframes.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
dat <- dat %>% 
    group_by(PROFILE, NTHREADS) %>% 
    filter(TIME == min(TIME))
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've done it with the comment by Ronak Shah. **Iff both dataframes share column names & values** (because of aggregating with MIN instead of MEAN), the simplest solution is:

```
data_aggr <- merge(data_aggr, data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider `ave`, the method to aggregate across different levels of factors. You can pass multiple groupings as separate arguments:

```
data <- read.table(text="PROFILE TIME   NTHREADS PARAM1 PARAM2 PARAM3
                         prof1   3.01   1        4      10     1
                         prof2   2.90   2        4      10     1
                         prof1   3.02   1        4      10     1
                         prof2   1.52   2        4      10     2
                         prof1   1.60   1        4      10     2", header=TRUE)

data$min_TIME <- ave(data$TIME, data$PROFILE, data$NTHREADS, FUN=min)
data

#   PROFILE TIME NTHREADS PARAM1 PARAM2 PARAM3 min_TIME
# 1   prof1 3.01        1      4     10      1     1.60
# 2   prof2 2.90        2      4     10      1     1.52
# 3   prof1 3.02        1      4     10      1     1.60
# 4   prof2 1.52        2      4     10      2     1.52
# 5   prof1 1.60        1      4     10      2     1.60
```